# php - regex - match "(posted|post|submitted) by:" from a text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, match

i need to match & replace with regex each occurence of string like theese:

**note:** *each string can be inside a text OR at the beginning of the text; in both case the regex should match everything from the starting point to the end of the line*

- Lorem Ipsum `Posted by` Someone on March...\n
- `Posted by:` Someone on March...\n
- `Posted` March by Someone...\n
- Lorem Ipsum `Post by` Someone on...\n
- `by` Someone on....\n
- `Submitted by:` Someone on...\n
- Lorem Ipsum `Submitted by` Someone on...\n

> - *`\n` mean just end of line*

this is what i have done, but seams to not work always as expected.

```
/(?:(posted|post|submitted)\s)(?:(by))(?:(.*))\s(.*)|/i
```

**/EDIT:**

ok, the problem is i need to match `posted|post|submitted by` both on beginning of the string and in the middle of it, and `by` only at the beginning of the string otherwise it will match also something like "by the way..."

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with your examples in [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)?

Comment: Do you need to capture any of those elements for reuse?  I'm assuming probably the "someone" and the month.  If so, is "someone" always going to be a single word, alpha characters only?

Comment: @Bobby B: i need to delete the entire line from where the posted|post|submitted|by start to the end.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: nice one, tnx for the link. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATED

```
/((?:^by\s)|(?:.*(?:Post|Submit[t]?)(?:ed)?[\w|\s]*by:?\s?))/im
```

Group index 1 will be your Posted|Submitted|... and everything to the left.

[Demo in browser](http://regexr.com?2td9b)

[image]

Comment: The [t]? could be written as just ..tt? but i did it for readability, also i'm not sure if it would always be "submitted" or some times "submit" so that's why i made the last "t" optional

Comment: tnx for this, but actually i don't need the second group i need just to replace everything next to the matched (by|posted|post|submitted).

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
preg_replace ('/((^by[^a-z])|(.*?(posted|post|submitted))).*\n?/im', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/((post(ed)?|submitted)\s)?(by|[a-z]* by):? .*/i
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
((Post|Posted|Submitted).*)|(by [\w]+ on).*
```

I ran that against your list on regexpal (www.regexpal.com)

Good luck!